# How to measure UV index?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, spectroscopy, photochemistry, spectrophotometry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I am a high school student so please apologise if I say something very dumb or irrelevant. I am conducting an experiment in which I want to find UV index at different points. Such as under shade, inside house, near beach etc. Anything will be greatly appreciated, also even if there is a device thats very expensive please tell me about that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Finding 'UV index' at a point might be difficult. UV index is an index created by I think was WHO, and is calculated using 
 - Thickness of ozone above
 - Cloud density of the area
 - Altitude of location
 - Sun's height
more about it here - https://www.who.int/uv/publications/en/UVIGuide.pdf
So I think you are better off finding the UV light intensity instead, using some measurement tools. There's few different options like photo reactive dyes, and digital scales, but probably the most cheap and quantitative data can be obtained using arduino or other similar development board and creating a small module yourself. Good Luck!

Comment: Hey first of all thanks for your help. Is there a way that I can convert the UV index into UV light intensity, vice-versa. I need to compare my results with the UV index in my city. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of conversion of UV index to any physically measurable units. It's more of a guideline of how harmful is the UV at that location at that time, and is multi-component. While light intensity is a physical measurement (But there's multiple ways of measuring, each with different meaning). Moreover, comparing your measurement directly with the city's UV index makes no physical sense, it's like comparing apples and oranges. On the other hand you could decide on how to measure UV and make your own index.

Comment: Thanks again!!! I did some research and I found this could you please tell me if this device is what I think it is. It converts the UV intensity into UV index measurement. - https://www.arpansa.gov.au/user-guide-uv-index-meter

Comment: I guess it works. It could provide you with similar index value to what city announces. That devices seems to use SiliconCarbide photodiode, so do a little research about what’s being measured and include that info in your project